# Memory Conservation with Manual Bit Fields vs. std::bitset

Tags: c++, bit-fields, std-bitset

I'm learning about bit flags and creating bit fields manually using bit-wise operators. I then came across bitsets, seemingly an easier and cleaner way of storing a field of bits. I understand the value of using bit fields as far as minimizing memory usage. After testing the sizeof(bitset), though, I'm having a hard time understanding how this is a better approach.

Consider:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{

    // Using Bit Set, Size = 8 Bytes
    const unsigned int i1 = 0;
    const unsigned int i2 = 1;

    std::bitset<8> mySet(0);

    mySet.set(i1);
    mySet.set(i2);

    std::cout << sizeof(mySet) << std::endl;

    // Manually managing bit flags

    const unsigned char t1 = 1 << 0;
    const unsigned char t2 = 1 << 1;

    unsigned char bitField = 0;
    bitField |= t1 | t2;

    std::cout << sizeof(bitField) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

The mySet is 8 bytes. The bitField is 1 byte.

Should I not use std::bitset if minimal memory usage is desired?

Comment: `bitset` has conversions to and from `unsigned long long`, making it not unreasonable to have that type stored internally. The type is also a lot more convenient if you need `bitset<1000>`. If you just need a few bits, an unsigned char might work better.

Comment: Bo, are you saying bitset pays off when working with a very large set of bits to manage? But for minimizing memory usage, I should stick with manual bit shifting?

Comment: If you use very few bits and minimal space is more important than the convenience of a ready made class, then yes. Some compilers might optimize the size of a small `bitset`, but not everyone.

Comment: @LoganWest -- Well, you really couldn't expect the size of a class with members to be a single byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the lowest possible memory footprint you shouldn't use `std::bitset`. It will likely require more memory than a plain built in type like `char` or `int` of equivalent effective size. Thus, it probably has memory overhead, but how much will depend on the implementation.

One major advantage of `std::bitset` is that it frees you from hardware-dependent implementations of various types. In theory, the hardware can use any representation for any type, as long as it fulfills some requirements in the C++ standard. Thus when you rely on `unsigned char t1 = 1` to be  `00000001` in memory, this is not actually guaranteed. But if you create a bitset and initialize it properly, it won't give you any nasty surprises.

A sidenote on bitfiddling: considering the pitfalls to fiddling with bits in this way, can you really justify this error-prone method instead of using `std::bitset` or even types like `int` and `bool`? Unless you're extremely resource constrained (e.g. MCU / DSP programming), I don't think you can.

> Those who play with bits will be bitten, and those who play with bytes will be bytten.

---

By the way, the `char bitField` you declare and manipulate using bitwise operators is a bit field, but it's not the C++ language notion of a bit field, which looks like this:

```
struct BitField{
    unsigned char flag1 : 1, flag2 : 1, flag3 : 1;
}
```

Loosely speaking, it is a data structure whose data member(s) are subdivided into separate variables. In this case the `unsigned char` of (presumably) 8 bits is used to create three 1-bit variables (`flag1`, `flag2` and `flag3`). It is explicitly subdivided, but at the end of the day this is just compiler-/language-assisted bit fiddling similar to what you did above. You can [read more about bit fields here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field).